# My website scales when printed, making black text look grey

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, media-type

I have a completely fluid website that is designed primarily for printing. It stretches beautifully to any window or paper size:

```
body { width: 100%; }
```

However, for printed pages, some of my black lines and text become grey and I have `1px` lines that don't print as solid lines, but more of a fuzzy grey dotted line. This seems to be because browsers are scaling the page on print, like the "Shrink To Fit" of IE.

So I see two options.

1. Specify line widths and font sizes using css units that work well on print, potentially fighting against browsers in-built mechanisms to make pages print well when everything is specified in pixels. *[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978335/specify-hairline-thickness-in-css-for-printing) works at part of that without much success.*
2. Find the `body` width (`8.5in`? `7.5in`? `90%`? `800px`?) which makes lines solid and text black for 8.5 inch wide paper.

Which approach is likely to be successful?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a separate stylesheet for print media, or perhaps just override offending styles with a `@media print { /* rules here */}` block at the end of your current stylesheet.

If you are designing a website for both screen and print, this will give you the most flexible way to independently control styling for both media.

Comment: Already been using `@media`, but my question is about how to get it to print properly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with the printer quality.  1px rendered in hi-res looks a bit different when it comes out of a 5 year old printer with print quality set to "fast draft".

Two easy troubleshooting options to try:

1. Either increase the print quality and print in full color, or try it from a different printer.
2. If it's possible, perhaps you could try to thicken the lines a bit?  I know it may not work with your design, but sometimes the simplest answers are best.

Good luck man.